# Geopandas plots as subfigures

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, geopandas

Say I have the following geodataframe that contains 3 polygon objects.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

p1=Polygon([(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)])
p2=Polygon([(3,3),(3,6),(6,6),(6,3)])
p3=Polygon([(3,.5),(4,2),(5,.5)])

gdf=gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[p1,p2,p3])
gdf['Value1']=[1,10,20]
gdf['Value2']=[300,200,100]
```

`gdf` content:

```
>>> gdf
                               geometry  Value1  Value2
0   POLYGON ((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))       1     300
1   POLYGON ((3 3, 3 6, 6 6, 6 3, 3 3))      10     200
2  POLYGON ((3 0.5, 4 2, 5 0.5, 3 0.5))      20     100
>>>
```

I can make a separate figure for each plot by calling `geopandas.plot()` twice. However, is there a way for me to plot both of these maps next to each other in the same figure as subfigures?

[image]

[image]

Comment: this question would be greatly improved by including the plotting commands you used to generate your figures.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Always *always* ***always*** create your matplotlib objects ahead of time and pass them to the plotting methods (or use them directly). Doing so, your code becomes:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import geopandas
from shapely import geometry

p1 = geometry.Polygon([(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)])
p2 = geometry.Polygon([(3,3),(3,6),(6,6),(6,3)])
p3 = geometry.Polygon([(3,.5),(4,2),(5,.5)])

gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(dict(
        geometry=[p1, p2, p3],
        Value1=[1, 10, 20],
        Value2=[300, 200, 100],
))

fig, (ax1, ax2) = pyplot.subplots(ncols=2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
gdf.plot(ax=ax1, column='Value1')
gdf.plot(ax=ax2, column='Value2')
```

Which gives me:

[image]

Comment: Hmm, actually when I run your code I get the following error message: "plot_multipolygon() got multiple values for keyword argument 'ax'". Perhaps we are using different versions of geopandas?

Comment: I'm on geopandas version 0.2.0

Answer (score 0):

```
// for plotting multiple GeoDataframe 
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file(geojson) 
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,4, figsize=(40,10))
axes[0].set_title('Some Title')
gdf.plot(ax=axes[0], column='Some column for coloring', cmap='coloring option')

axes[0].set_title('Some Title')
gdf.plot(ax=axes[0], column='Some column for coloring', cmap='coloring option')
```